# SWRevealViewController won't work after timed launch screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

Please help. I have made a time delay to my launch screen in my `AppDelegate`. After that my `SWRevealViewController` menu won't work :-( I have deleted the time delay again, but my SWRevealViewController still won't work....

What can be wrong?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:4];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I changed the simulator to iPhone 5 and then back to iPhone 6, then the SWRevealViewcontroller worked again